# One Critical Value despite being on a compact set

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, compactness

Let $\alpha > 1$ and $s >0$
find all the local extrema of $f: \mathbb R_{\geq 0} \times \mathbb R_{\geq 0}\to\mathbb R, f(x,y):=x^{\alpha}+y^{\alpha}$
under the constraint that $h(x,y):=x+y-s=0$

In the solutions we found that using lagrange multipliers $(\frac{s}{2},\frac{s}{2})$ is the only candidate, **HOWEVER**, defining

$M:=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R_{\geq 0}^{2}:x+y=s\}$, I would assume that $M$ is compact and therefore $f|_{M}$ needs to take on a minimum and a maximum, but I have only found one candidate, how can that be?

Comment: Your domain is a closed interval, and you have to consider the endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate slightly on @Lubin's comment:

The method of Lagrange multipliers can't be directly applied to this problem. Lagrange multipliers are used to solve optimization problems of the form

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rl}
\min\ & f(x) \\
\text{s.t.}\ & g_i(x)=0\text{ for }i=1,\dots,m
\end{array}
\end{equation}

*i.e.* a problem completely defined by equality constraints. However, in your problem, you require that $x_1,x_2\geqslant0$, which are inequality constraints. If you neglect these inequality constraints, then you actually *do* only have one stationary point. When you add the inequality constraints, you have two more, one at each endpoint of the interval.

The appropriate generalization of Lagrange multipliers to handle inequality constraints are the [Karush-Kuhn-Tucker (KKT) Conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions).

Comment: You say, "If you neglect these inequality constraints, then you actually do only have one stationary point,"  **BUT** surely if we neglect the inqualities for $x$ and $y$ we can use the method of lagrange mutlipliers and subsequently we would have to get at least two stationary points (i.e. global max and global min, as we are on a compact set). Unless one stationary point means that the global maximum is equal to the global minimum, thus implying that the function is constant

Comment: @SABOY The domain is not compact when you neglect the inequality constraints. You can make the objective function arbitrarily large.